# Missing ARM template for Sitecore 9 Update 1 in Azure PaaS

Tags: azure-resource-manager, arm-template

I see Sitecore 9 Update 1 has been released recently but it is missing in azure ARM templates.

Can anybody provide information on it's availability or am i missing something?

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: would that be available or we can go ahead with the initial release ?

Comment: Please edit your original question to include the details of your question